# API Timestamp Design

Tags: api, timestamp

quick question
i got a new related app plan to design so just need to know what is the best method to update the app with new data only rather then keep loading the API the idea of it is to only pull new data at the time the app was installed, any previous data will not be loaded in the app

Currently we planned to do this this way

1) First run use current time stamp  and we store this timestamp

2) Second call we do is call the previous timestamp of (1) and store the current one (2)

3) third call we do we call previous timestamp of (2) and store current one which we call (3)

now if new data has been added between the calls of the timestamp then the API will reflect this the API will only show new data that has been added

so for example

1) First call
www.site.com/datetime=1234567890

This will return No Items

In between this time new data was added

2) Second Call (Take Previous Timestamp and store current timestamp)
Previous:www.site.com/datetime=1234567890

New: www.site.com/datetime=1234567891

this will return data in the API

3) 3rd Call
(Take Previous Timestamp and store currently timestamp)

Previous: www.site.com/datetime=1234567891 
New: www.site.com/datetime=1234567899

Would something like this work or is there a better way of doing it?

We dont want to load API every single time thus each new timestamp query is only returning new items if applicable

Answer (score 0):

Typically this is done with conditional headers, such as `If-modified-since` if you want to use a timestamp, or `If-none-match` if you wanted to use an ETag for versioning instead. You can see [RFC 7232](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-3) for more information on conditional headers.

Typically your API would be broken up into multiple resources, so that you're only getting the chunks that have changed rather than having an all-or-nothing.